# How to get value of customer custom attribute load by customer Id in phtml file in Magento2.3.0?

Tags: magento2, phtml, custom-attributes

How to get the value of customer custom attribute load by customer Id in phtml file in Magento2.3.0?

```
$customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId); 
$value = $customer->getCustomAttribute('business type)->getValue();
```

I have referred many links, but not able to achieve the value.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what you tried so that I can correct it and make it work.

Comment: $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
                $value = $customer->getCustomAttribute('business type)->getValue(); and I have also tried with objectmanager. But not able to achieve the value.

Comment: amy should by use attribute code in getCustomAttribute() method. Don't be use attribute label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    

/* get Customer id */
$customer = $session->getCustomer();
$customerId = $customer->getId();
$customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();

/* load customer collection by Customer id */
$customerRepository = $objectManager
        ->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepository->getById($customerId);

/*get customer custom attribute value by customer attribute code */
$cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')->getValue();
```

**Note: Code tested**

Comment: I hope you got answer

Comment: Nope, Page showing empty..

Comment: which phtml file are you working?

Comment: It is my custom phtml file.

Comment: try with logged in user

Comment: Okay will check

Comment: If it works, mark as correct.It will be useful for others

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Just now only checked. It's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution